# Indexing technique in Ehcache

Tags: java, ehcache, lucene

I just went to almost all the documentation of ehcache. They are using indexes to perform queries in cache. What they didn't mentioned is what technique they are using?

Also I want to use EHcache as a cache store and create index on that cache with lucene. Does anyone know how to do that i already did an exhaustive search but didn't find anything is it even possible to with EHcache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ehcache has different types of storage. If you refer to the most commonly used one ([`MemoryStore`](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/store/MemoryStore.html)), it uses [`SelectableConcurrentHashMap`](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/store/chm/SelectableConcurrentHashMap.html) which is a somewhat customized version of [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). Just to be clear, this is completely different from how Lucene works.

If you want to Lucene-index your cache entries, one of the ways of doing that would be implementing [`CacheEventListener`](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/event/CacheEventListener.html) and calling relevant Lucene APIs on each cache event (remove, put, expired, etc.).

Comment: Can you direct me to some link where i can read more about internal working of EHcache its very critical for me to know that.

Comment: You can read Ehcache user guide, buy a book or look at the source code. I prefer the latter; Ehcache isn't a product which has millions lines of code and steep learning curve.

Comment: As a heads up, the CacheEventListener approach discussed above wouldn't work, as it wouldn't give you the ordering guarantees you'd want even on a per key.